# How to keep some Strings in a text file?

Tags: java, file, text

I have a text file which has a format like this:

```
ab
cd
ef
gh
ij
..
```

I want to erase Strings after "ef", I mean after running my program the text file structure be like this:

```
ab
cd 
ef
```

I'm using netbeans IDE and using java codes. Could any one help?
It's my tried code but it just keeps Strings before "ef" in a String, but I have no idea how to do the else!

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:\\info.txt"));
try {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = br.readLine();

    while (!(line.equals("ef"))) {
        sb.append(line);
       // sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    String everything = sb.toString();
    System.out.print(everything);
   // System.out.print(sb);
} finally {
    br.close();
}
```

Comment: where is your tried code ?

Comment: I added my code, but it's not complete at all. @Ramanlfc

Comment: Well right now you loop over all lines until you reach "ef" and then stop. So no wonder you are getting that output.

Comment: but my code doesn't change my file, I want the text file to be corrected in the form I said. @Florian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example to correct your file

```
final String fileName = "E:\\info.txt";
String everything = "";

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  String line = br.readLine();

  while (!(line.equals("ef"))) {
    sb.append(line).append("\n");
    // sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
    line = br.readLine();
  }

  sb.append(line);
  everything = sb.toString();
  System.out.print(everything);
}

final File file = new File(fileName);
file.delete();

try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileName)) {
  writer.write(everything);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Apache commons-io's [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) like in the following example:

```
private final String FILE_NAME = "E:\\info.txt";

public void test() throws IOException {
    File file = new File(FILE_NAME);
    List<String> strings = FileUtils.readLines(file);
    int ef = strings.indexOf("ef");
    List<String> stringBeforeEF = strings.subList(0, ef);
    FileUtils.writeLines(file, stringBeforeEF);
}
```